# Puppet Duplicate declaration: Class

Tags: mac-osx, puppet, mac, infrastructure, operating-system

I'm bit new to puppet, but I'm not sure how this would become a duplicate declaration, can someone please give me some direction whether this is a correct usage of class passing params or not?

```
Error: Duplicate declaration: Class[Jenkins_dotfiles] is already declared in file /tmp/puppet-manifests-test/manifests/site.pp:193; cannot redeclare at /tmp/puppet-manifests-test/manifests/site.pp:193
```

With this code:

```
$user = 'jenkins'
$group = 'staff'
$home = "/Users/${user}"
...
if ($is_jenkins) {
    class {
        'jenkins_dotfiles':
            home => '/var/root',
            user => 'root';
        'jenkins_dotfiles':
            home => $home,
            user => $user;
```

jenkins_dotfiles/manifests/init.pp

```
 class jenkins_dotfiles($home, $user) {
 ...
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **are** declaring it twice. Once with the parameter values `'/var/root'`, `'root'`, the other with the parameters `$home` and `$user`. You probably should be making `jenkins_dotfiles` a defined type, not a class.